# paragraph spacing goes awry when tcolorbox is inside wrapfigure

Tags: paragraphs, tcolorbox, wrapfigure

I have a `tcolorbox` environment that I use on its own, and sometimes inside a `wrapfigure`. On its own, it works perfectly - paragraphs are spaced according to my document's `parskip` and `parindent`. However, inside `wrapfigure` those settings seem to be ignored.

Here is a MWE:

```
% !TEX program = xelatex

\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{sidebar}[2][]{
    parbox=false, % normal paragraph spacing (unless wrapped!)
    sharp corners,
    colframe=black,
    colback=black!15!white,
    title=#2,
    #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidebar}{Test without wrapping}
    Paragraph 1.

    Paragraph 2.
\end{sidebar}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{sidebar}{Test with wrapping and no explicit parksip}
        Paragraph 1.

        Paragraph 2.
    \end{sidebar}
\end{wrapfigure}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
    \begin{sidebar}{Test with wrapping and explicit parskip}
        \setlength{\parskip}{3mm}\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}Paragraph 1.

        Paragraph 2.
    \end{sidebar}
\end{wrapfigure}

\end{document}
```

Here is the output:

[image]

Is there any way I can avoid the need to explicitly specify `parskip` (and `parindent`) inside my wrapped `tcolorbox`?

Comment: Have you tried the `parskip` class option? Or you can always add it to the default code executed at the beginning of the boxes using `tcolorbox`'s configuration, can't you? Possibly annoying, but you don't have to do it for every box - only once or once per type of box, depending on your needs, I guess. You could also just box the box, I suspect. Certainly if you boxed first, it should work. But even inside might do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that you should use the `parskip` class option with KOMA classes, rather than `parskip` or, worse, setting the dimensions manually. If the default `parskip` isn't appropriate, see KOMA's documentation for the various values you can set it to.

You can restore the required skip using the `hooks` library. For example,

```
\documentclass[parskip]{scrbook}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{hooks}
\usepackage{kantlipsum}
\newlength\myskip
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \setlength\myskip{\parskip}%
}
\newtcolorbox[auto counter]{sidebar}[2][]{
  parbox=false, % normal paragraph spacing (unless wrapped!)
  sharp corners,
  colframe=black,
  colback=black!15!white,
  before upper app={\par\parskip=\myskip},
  title=#2,
  #1
}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidebar}{Test without wrapping}
  Paragraph 1.

  Paragraph 2.
\end{sidebar}

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{sidebar}{Test with wrapping and no explicit parksip}
    Paragraph 1.

    Paragraph 2.
  \end{sidebar}
\end{wrapfigure}
\kant[1]

\begin{wrapfigure}{r}{0.5\linewidth}
  \begin{sidebar}{Test with wrapping and explicit parskip}
    \setlength{\parskip}{3mm}\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}Paragraph 1.

    Paragraph 2.
  \end{sidebar}
\end{wrapfigure}
\kant[2]

\end{document}
```

[image: restored skip]